# How to change permission in 11.04 version of ubuntu for root in the file system

Tags: 11.04

Recently installed 11.04 version of ubuntu. Wanted to create a folder in the root of the fileSystem, but the persmission was denied. Tried with chown and chmod but no result.

Kindly assist me

Answer (score 1):

You have to be root to be able to create a directory in /.

So if you have sudo installed you can just type `sudo mkdir /<yourdir>` and change the permissions afterwards with e.g. `sudo chown $USER:$USER /<yourdir>`. If you don't have sudo installed you have to login as root (type `su` in a terminal) and execute the commands without the preceding sudo.

If I understood you correctly you tried a to change the ownership of the root file system. Don't do that!

Comment: You can assume sudo to be installed since we all use Ubuntu ;)